# Как сделать module.exports для db.each?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sqlite3

Не понимаю, как сделать экспорт each, данный код в консоль не выводит вообще ничего

```js
const dbeach=require('./DBeach');
dbeach(`SELECT login FROM users WHERE chatid=123`,(err,res)=>{
    console.log(res);
});
```

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/users.db', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
});
module.exports=(statement)=>{
    return db.each(statement);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, при передаче теряется обратный вызов. Попробуйте так:

```js
module.exports=(statement, cb)=>{
    return db.each(statement, cb);
};
```